# Como emitir Nota Fiscal Eletronica no mode teste no Woocommerce?

Tags: testes, woocommerce, plugin-wordpress

Como faço para emitir gratuitamente as notas fiscais, versão teste no Woocommerce? Para testar o plugin, da WebminarBR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rapaz, não sei se já te responderam e se era WebminarBR, sei do WebManiaBR.
Mas no próprio site da webmaniabr tem as instruções https://webmaniabr.com/blog/emita-nf-e-na-sua-loja-virtual-woocommerce/

Espero que ajude.